# Can C# TransactionScope can be used with SSH.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope, ssh.net

I am wondering which are the uses cases for dotnet [TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-3.0) class.

This is to be used only with sql operations?

Can I use it, for example, to try and rename a file using a SftpClient with [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET)?

Comment: Renaming a file is anyways a single atomic operation , why do you need a Transaction for that...?

Comment: `TransactionScope` is not magic; it merely expresses intent. It is up to providers of transactional operations to actually build support for enlisting in an active `TransactionScope`. This need not be restricted to databases, but that is the common use case. I have no idea if SSH.NET includes such support, but I would be very surprised indeed if it did. Even local file systems typically don't offer this (NTFS is a notable exception, but even Microsoft considers that deprecated as not enough applications actually use it, and there is no built-in support for it in .NET).